# Unable to create/update fullfillments using shopify-api-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I'm trying to create fulfillments for my order but whenever I try I'm getting

```
HTTPError: Response code 400 (Bad Request)
```

Here's how I'm trying to update it

```
const fulfillment = {
        tracking_company: "DHL",
        tracking_number: "123123",
        tracking_url: "trackingdhl.com/tracking/123123"
           }

const fulfill = await shopify.fulfillment.create(orderId , fulfillment) 
console.log('fulfill ======>' , fulfill)
```

Comment: what was the reason behind this error? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: I need to update the method for calling the fulfilment API. Shopify has made changes to its fulfilment process.